# Running Malwarebytes under Wine 1.2.2

Tags: software-installation, wine, 10.04, malware

How can I get Malwarebytes to run with wine under 10.04?  I have wine version 1.2.2 at default settings.  Is there anything specific I need to do in order to get Malwarebytes to run?  I am using the program to slave HDD's from windows machines.  Being a technician it would make my life infinitely easier if I could get this to work.

I guess I should mention that I successfully installed malwarebytes, but I can't get it to run. I double click the icon and nothing ever happens.

Update:

I looked at the appdb for wine and saw that it works with the older version 1.34. I installed winetricks as suggested and it works fine with the older version.  I am now looking up how to update the definitions manually, which shouldn't be a problem because I've had to do that in windows a few times.

Comment: it would be immensely helpful if you could attach the terminal output as well ^^. to get this, right click the launch, click properties, copy and paste the executable code into a terminal and run it, then save the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the Wine headquarters, they have [an entry on Malwarebytes](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9263).

Did you already read the information there?

**EDIT:**

googling for your missing DLL, it turns out that using winetricks (a script which you can download, see [this page](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks)), you can install this missing library by running:

```
$ winetricks vb6run
```

Answer (score 1):

Install [winetricks](http://packages.ubuntu.com/winetricks) [image: Install winetricks], and then use that to install (Microsoft Visual Basic 6 it looks like, possibly just a few missing dlls.) You could also grab the dlls from dllfiles.com.

*EDIT: looks like steabert got it before me :D*

Answer (score 0):

To get Malwarebytes to run with Wine under 10.04, you can try the following steps:

Make sure you have the latest version of Wine installed. Upgrading to a newer version might resolve any compatibility issues.

Check the Wine AppDB for specific instructions or workarounds for running Malwarebytes with Wine. Sometimes, users share their experiences and solutions there.

Consider using winetricks, a helpful tool for installing and managing various components and libraries in Wine. It can assist in setting up dependencies that Malwarebytes may require.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).